# How to send data between 2 fragments in tab layout (view pager )

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I want to send data from fragment to another when i clicked the relative layout
there is the code of fragments and the Activity ,screen shot from android mobile emlator
(counter one fragment when the counter increase the counter in two fragment also increase as total counts )

```
public class CounterFragment extends Fragment {

 TextView textView;
Button reset;
private int counter = 0;

public static CounterFragment getInstance(){
    CounterFragment counterFragment = new CounterFragment();
    return counterFragment;
}



public CounterFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_counter, container, false);
    textView=view.findViewById(R.id.countertext);
    reset=view.findViewById(R.id.reset);
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout=view.findViewById(R.id.reltivee);


    relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            counter++;
            textView.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

**fragment 2**
public class Allcounts extends Fragment {

```
TextView all;
Button resett;
int counterr=0;




public static Allcounts getInstance(){
    Allcounts allcounts = new Allcounts();
    return allcounts;
}


public Allcounts() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_allcounts, container, false);



    return view;
}
```

}

**Activity**

```
public class Counter extends AppCompatActivity  {
TabLayout tabLayout;
ViewPager viewPager;
 Allcounts allcounts;
CounterFragment counterFragment;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_counter);



    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    getTabs();



   }

public void getTabs(){
    final CounterAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new CounterAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(Allcounts.getInstance(),"المجموع الكلي"); // Allcounts.getInstance() should be in `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem()`
            viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(CounterFragment.getInstance(),"العداد");  // CounterFragment.getInstance() should be in `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem()`

            viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Use a ViewModel scoped to a shared scope